# Refresh table on site.com page

Tags: site.com, table

I do a website with site.com. My page is doing like this : 
- a form for add a data for my object
- a table with the data of my object.
 
When I add a data with my form, it's necessary I do F5(refresh) for data appears in the table. 
It's possible to do this automatic ?

Comment: Can you post your code. If you're using visualforce you can use partial (Ajax) page refreshes using action Function / region

Comment: it's possible with site.com to use visualforce page ?  I use a visualforce page in my application but actually not in site.com.

Comment: Sorry but i can't post my code... in site.com i can't see my code when I use a page element by default. If it's possible, can you tell me how ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by specifying *Show another page* for *When Successful* property of the *SUBMIT* properties of the form which would result in the entire page refreshing, including the table.

1. Select the Form on you page in the Site.com Studio so that you can see the Properties panel on the right side of the page.
2. There is a *SUBMIT* section that has a property called *When Successful* that is a picklist with the values *Display a message* and *Show another page*.
3. Choose *Show another page* then you will be able to enter a value for *Page URL*.
4. For *Page URL* enter the URL of your current page.  For example, if you have a page called LeadFormPage then enter LeadFormPage (If you are using aliases or redirects you can use those as well).

[image]

The result will be that when the form is submitted successfully the entire page is refreshed, showing the end user the latest data available in the table.

This isn't a partial page refresh, though.  To do that, I believe that you would need to handle the asynchronous form submission, response, and table refresh yourself using JavaScript.